# Convert comma separated string of floats into list?

Tags: python, string, list

I need to define a function `txtnum(L)` that takes a string of comma separated floats such as `"1.5,2.5,3.5"` as a parameter and converts it into a list `[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]`.

I have tried using `.split()`, `.join()`, `map()`, etc and cannot get anything to return a list that does NOT include quotations. I'm pretty new to Python and a little lost here.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8):

You need to convert the datatype of splitted vars because splitting alone string gives you a list of strings.

```
>>> s = "1.5,2.5,3.5"
>>> [float(i) for i in s.split(',')]
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
>>>
```

or

```
>>> map(float, s.split(','))
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
```

Answer (score 2):

`1.5,2.5,3.5` is a valid `tuple` literal in Python (without parentheses, yes, but it doesn't matter), so you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on it:

```
In [1]: import ast

In [2]: s = '1.5,2.5,3.5'

In [3]: ast.literal_eval(s)
Out[3]: (1.5, 2.5, 3.5)
```

If you really need a list, that's easy, too:

```
In [4]: list(ast.literal_eval(s))
Out[4]: [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
s = "1.5,2.5,3.5"
strArr = s.split(',')
import numpy as np
x = np.array(strArr, dtype='|S4')
arrFloat = x.astype(np.float)
print arrFloat
```