# Is there in Python a way to read two floats from a string

Tags: python

I am reading a text file which contains in each line two floats separated by a comma (x,y), like this :

```
5.2,4.4
2.2,7.2
3.6,6.9
```

I need to read each two floats from each lines, to do some calculation on them, for exemple the first line, i have 5.2 + 4.4, then print it at this end like this : x = 5.2, y = 4.4 and the sum = 9.6

Here what i have tried :

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    myFile = f.read()
    a = myFile.splitlines()
    (here i cant find how to read the floats to do the sum)
    print ('x= {}, y= {}, sum= {}'.format(x, y, sum))
```

Comment: Just take each line and split on commas via `line.split(',')`, then call `float()` on each element. What part are you not sure of how to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert comma separated string of floats into list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450565/convert-comma-separated-string-of-floats-into-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing is that the numbers will come out of the file as strings, so you have to convert them into floats before you can add them.

You can do something like this:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        x, y = line.split(',')
        sum_ = float(x) + float(y)
        print('x= {}, y= {}, sum= {}'.format(x, y, sum_))
```

I called it `sum_` because there's a built-in function called `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help:

```py
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    data = [tuple(i.strip().split(",")) for i in f.readlines()]

sums = [float(i[0])+float(i[1]) for i in data]
print(sums)
```

Whats going on here?

- i loop through each line, creating a tuple of the numbers delimited by a comma
- i make an array of sums from each element of the tuple added together

and just in case you want it here's the one liner because why not :^)

```py
print([float(i[0])+float(i[1]) for i in [tuple(i.strip().split(",")) for i in open("text.txt", "r").readlines()]])
```

Comment: This is going to do string concatenation, you need to cast to floats.

Comment: @kwinkunks yeah sorry about that, i just caught it before you sent that, should be edited and fine now

Answer (score 0):

Just go over the lines and use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> line = '5.2,4.4'

>>> x, y = ast.literal_eval(line)
>>> x, y, x+y
(5.2, 4.4, 9.600000000000001)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before performing any operation convert number to float after reading file.
You can try this

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
r = [x.split(",") for x in [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]]
print(r) 
#[['5.2', '4.4'], ['2.2', '7.2'],['3.6','6.9']]
results = [float(x[0]) + float(x[1]) for x in r]
print(results)
#[9.6, 9.4, 10.5]
```